# How to change language in iSpeech SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, ispeech

I am trying to use iSpeech SDK for iOS.

I am using Free version.

I'm fine with English Text To Speech with following codes.

```
 [ispeech ISpeechSpeak:@"HELLO World"];
```

But I also want to use multiple language like japanese, korean, etc...

How can I change language in iSpeech?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the following examples which might help you; 
[DotNet Sample](https://www.ispeech.org/downloads/ispeech-.net-sdk-docs-demo-20110614.zip) and
[Web Examples](http://www.ispeech.org/developer/gettingstarted/web)

From that you should be able to make sense of what you trying to do, as the API is the same across Platform.

You might try:
    `[ispeech setVoice:@"jpjapanesemale"];`

Voices are listed in the ISSpeechSynthesisVoices.h header file